Is OpenCV permanently allocating memory for each thread that calls cv::findChessboardCornersSB?
I have a large number of images (roughly 2500) that contain chessboards used for camera calibration. I'm launching several background threads to call cv::findChessboardCornersSB to find the chessboard corners in these images. While choosing the optimal number of threads to launch, I noticed that quite a large amount of memory was left permanently allocated even after all analysis was complete.
After testing with different numbers of threads (1, 5, 10, 15, and 20), I've found that there is a definite correlation between the number of threads launched and the amount of memory left allocated when analysis is complete, and it's quite large. For example, launching 20 threads to analyze these 2500 chessboard images leaves 3760 MiB allocated after completion. Please see the graph below.
I know that my code isn't leaking, because I can continuously queue up analysis of more and more images indefinitely, and the memory consumption, while high, does not increase over time.
I'm hoping someone who knows OpenCV better than me can explain what's causing this, and hopefully whether or not I can do anything to free this memory.
As requested, here is a minimal reproducible example:
// Test controls
#define TEST_THREADS_COUNT (15)
#define TEST_IMAGES_COUNT 3000

// The structure that contains the data needed by the background thread to perform the chessboard corner finding
typedef struct {
    uint64_t uID;
    cv::Mat FrameImage;
    int nRows; int nCols;
} ChessboardCornerFindingTaskThreadData;

// The vector of tasks waiting to be completed, and the mutex that protects access to it
std::vector<ChessboardCornerFindingTaskThreadData> *g_pWaitingTasksVector = NULL;
boost::mutex g_WaitingTasksVectorMutex;

// Whether or not the test is ready to start, and whether or not it's been completed
std::atomic<bool> g_bTestReadyToStart(false);
std::atomic<bool> g_bTestComplete(false);

// The function to run in each background thread
void* TestThreadFunc(void *pArg)
{
    // Variables used in each loop iteration
    bool bHasTask = false;
    bool bLastTask = false;
    bool bChessboardFound = false;
    ChessboardCornerFindingTaskThreadData TaskToComplete;

    // While we're busy analyzing frames
    while (true)
    {
        // If the test is done
        if (g_bTestComplete.load())
        {
            // Break out of this thread's loop
            break;
        }

        // We have not yet determined that a task is available
        bHasTask = false;

        // If we're ready to start
        if (g_bTestReadyToStart.load())
        {
            // Lock the mutex that protects access to the vector of tasks
            g_WaitingTasksVectorMutex.lock();

            // If a task is available
            if ((NULL != g_pWaitingTasksVector) && (0 < g_pWaitingTasksVector->size()))
            {
                // Get a copy of the task to complete
                TaskToComplete = (*g_pWaitingTasksVector)[0];

                // Remove this one from the vector
                g_pWaitingTasksVector->erase(g_pWaitingTasksVector->begin() + 0);

                // Request minimal vector allocation
                g_pWaitingTasksVector->shrink_to_fit();

                // Set that we have a task for this loop iteration
                bHasTask = true;
            }

            // Unlock the mutex that protects access to the vector of tasks
            g_WaitingTasksVectorMutex.unlock();
        }

        // If we have a task to perform
        if (bHasTask)
        {
            // Execute the chessboard corner finding
            std::vector<cv::Point2f> FoundCorners;
            bChessboardFound = cv::findChessboardCornersSB(TaskToComplete.FrameImage, cv::Size(TaskToComplete.nCols, TaskToComplete.nRows), FoundCorners, (cv::CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv::CALIB_CB_EXHAUSTIVE));
            
            // Release this frame's data
            TaskToComplete.FrameImage.release();

            // Get whether or not this is the last task
            bLastTask = (TaskToComplete.uID >= TEST_IMAGES_COUNT);
        }

        // Or, if we don't have a task to perform right now
        else
        {
            // Wait before checking again
            usleep(1000);
        }

        // If this is the last task
        if (bLastTask)
        {
            // Set that the test is complete so that other threads can return from their loops
            g_bTestComplete.store(true);

            // Lock the mutex that protects access to the vector of tasks
            g_WaitingTasksVectorMutex.lock();

            // If the vector is still allocated
            if (NULL != g_pWaitingTasksVector)
            {
                // Delete it
                delete g_pWaitingTasksVector;
                g_pWaitingTasksVector = NULL;
            }

            // Unlock the mutex that protects access to the vector of tasks
            g_WaitingTasksVectorMutex.unlock();

            // Break out of this thread's loop
            break;
        }
    }

    // Nothing to return here
    return NULL;
}


// Start the test
void StartTest()
{
    // Create the vector of tasks that the background threads will complete
    g_pWaitingTasksVector = new std::vector<ChessboardCornerFindingTaskThreadData>;

    // We are not yet ready to start until all tasks have been queued up
    g_bTestReadyToStart.store(false);

    // The test is not complete
    g_bTestComplete.store(false);
    
    // For each thread to launch
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_THREADS_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        // Launch this background thread
        pthread_t ThisThread;
        pthread_create((&ThisThread), NULL, TestThreadFunc, NULL);
    }

    // An ID to assign to each task
    uint64_t uID = 0;

    // For each test image
    for (int iTest = 0; iTest < TEST_IMAGES_COUNT; ++iTest)
    {
        // Increment the task ID
        ++uID;

        // Fill in a data structure that the background thread will use to perform its analysis
        ChessboardCornerFindingTaskThreadData ThisTask;
        ThisTask.uID = uID;
        ThisTask.FrameImage = cv::imread(std::string("/media/images/TestFrame.png"), cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        ThisTask.nRows = 50;
        ThisTask.nCols = 17;

        // Add this task to the vector
        g_WaitingTasksVectorMutex.lock();
        g_pWaitingTasksVector->push_back(ThisTask);
        g_WaitingTasksVectorMutex.unlock();
    }

    // Flag the waiting background threads that they should begin analysis
    g_bTestReadyToStart.store(true);
}



can you make it more minimaler, perhaps minimalest? [mre]

No, it doesn't allocate memory permanently.
See the source code which is quite transparent and shows usage only of dynamically allocated memory which is released when execution is done.
VmRSS (Virtual Memory Resident Set Size) tells how much of process memory (out of all VM memory) is now in physical memory. So, this is quite normal that if your process uses memory, it goes to physical memory and its size grows.
The VmRSS is inaccurate metric for measure used memory. See at the Linux manual page - proc_pid_status

VmRSS  Resident set size.  Note that the value here is the sum of RssAnon, RssFile, and RssShmem. This value                      is inaccurate; see /proc/pid/statm above.

You shouldn't rely on thee shrink_to_fit(), as well in the:
    // Request minimal vector allocation
    g_pWaitingTasksVector->shrink_to_fit();

since per shrink_to_fit:

It is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size(). It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled.

And as a note, your reasoning about absence of leaks is incorrect. Leaks could be "conditional", in your case the leak could take place once per thread (when you start it, uses first time or cyclic, when you keep something leak-ready till the end of the loop, like keeping every time updated pointer to memory which never will be realeased).

This is a good comment, but not an answer to OP's question. You can tell by how your post ends with "[we need] to see how you use ", AKA you're asking for a [mre] here. Requests for clarification go in comments, not answers.

@TylerH, wrong use of measurement tool is the answer. And I explained why he gets the results he gets. Anyway, if this won't help him, I don't insist.

Thanks for the tip, @DamirTenishev. I'll investigate using a more proper measurement than VmRSS, but either way the fact is that if I use too many threads, the OS eventually just kills the app (sends SIGKILL) because it's using too much memory.

@user2062604, well, every thing comes with its price, so thread is never for free (especially "too many" of them), but in case you have too much expenses for each thread, check with the proper tool and show us (as stated in comments) your source code (memory management) so that we could exclude obvious mistake. Let us know the result, it is always interesting to know the truth (especially when you punished - by down-votes in this case -  for it ;) ).

@DamirTenishev just to be clear, I did not down-vote you. Anyway, the issue is not the amount of memory that is being consumed during analysis (obviously it makes sense that we'll use more memory with more threads concurrently processing these images), the issue is that the more threads we launch, the more we seem to be left with after all analysis is complete. Seems a little odd to me, which is why I need to understand what's happening.

@user2062604, I never told you did ;) For sure this was from TylerH, who left the original comment under the answer. And, of course, I am just kidding on this matter, don't pay much attention to jokes. Getting back to the subject, you missed my point. When you get more threads, you got more memory used in pike. When you release memory (if you really do!), the memory is released by C++ memory management, but still belongs to the process VM and loaded (more with more threads) to physical memory, here the inaccuracy of VmRSS comes to play, as well. So, this explain things.

Wrong use of a measurement tool might be a useful tip but it still doesn't address the question of whether OpenCV is permanently allocating memory for each thread that it calls, which is what OP's question asks.

@TylerH, you missed the point. My answer stresses that even if memory is not permanently allocated, it could be reflected in VmRSS due to two reasons: (1) It shows the physical memory footprint from VM, which grows but doesn't decrease immediately; at least C++ delete/free doesn't force the memory reported by VmRSS to be dropped at once; (2) VmRSS  is imprecise which is a long story to cover here and this could lead to this effect, as well. See the root: VmRSS is not the tool to measure currently used by C++ program memory.

@TylerH, well, if you insist in wording, I've glanced into the source code and updated the answer. No, OpenCV doesn't allocate memory permanently; the source code is quite simple and transparent for this. So, we are getting back to the wrong measurement tool which led to wrong assumption.

Thank you for your edits, now your answer addresses the question asked! Protip, you should expect users to "insist on wording" because wording is what is used to convey knowledge. If you don't use words that address a question, how can you expect someone to understand how it... addresses the question?

@DamirTenishev looking at the man pages you linked to, they all say that VmRSS is inaccurate, and to look instead to /proc/pid/statm. What value in /proc/pid/statm do you suggest is the proper measurement to look at instead of VmRSS?

Well, Linux is pain, so I would port to Windows and compare behavior, if it persists, Windows has lots of tools for this. If you love pain, the recommended reading is How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process; it is old, but provides the necessary basics and if you are fine to read sources, look at the implementation at the libstatgrab.org. You shouldn’t rely on the shrink_to_fit, as well. Updated the answer.

@DamirTenishev Thanks for your work on this. I'm close to accepting your answer, but I just want to address one loose end before I do that. Your point about not relying on shrink_to_fit is technically correct (note that my comment specifically says 'request'), and it's important that future readers understand this, but note that when the test is completed, I'm deleting the vector entirely, thereby guaranteeing it's not still holding onto memory. For the benefit of future readers, I think your answer should make note of that in order to be as complete as possible.

@user2062604, agreed. Let's wait for the results of your research and update all things accordingly. It would be nice if you could test this on Windows. It would give you not only additional tools for testing, but OS with another threads and memory management approach. If you won't be able to find the final answer, let me know, I will check your code on Windows when have some spare time.

@DamirTenishev sounds good. But, I will not be able to try any of this on Windows, and it might not be until next week that I could try any new metrics, so it'll be a few days. Just so you don't think I've abandoned this question.

@DamirTenishev I have changed from looking at VmRSS to instead looking at the total amount allocated in all arenas including mmapped from malloc_stats() instead, and this reveals that the amount of memory left allocated after all analysis is complete does not change with the number of threads used, just like you said. Thanks for all your work on this. I'm now accepting your answer.

@user2062604, nice to hear. You are welcome. Some comments above your plan was  "when the test is completed, I'm deleting the vector entirely, thereby guaranteeing it's not still holding onto memory. For the benefit of future readers, I think your answer should make note of that in order to be as complete as possible". Do you plan to change something or we could keep both question wording (source) and answer as is?
